# How do I control who can see my Friends List?

Tags: facebook, privacy, friend-list

I don't want the entire world to see who I am friends with on Facebook.

How do I control who can see my list of friends?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To adjust who can see your Friends section:

- Go to your profile.
- Click Friends below your cover photo.
- Click at the top of the page and select `Edit Privacy` from the dropdown menu.
- Select an audience (ex: Friends, Public, Only me) to choose who you share your friend list with on your profile.

This is well explained on Facebook help page: [Who can see the Friends section of my profile](https://www.facebook.com/help/115450405225661)

Answer (score 3):

Follow these simple steps.

> - Click the “Friends” button underneath your cover photo. This will  open a list of all of your friends.
> - Click the “Manage” button. This is the little square button next to    the “+Find Friends” button. It has a pencil icon on it.
> - Select “Edit Privacy”. This will open a new window where you can    adjust your privacy settings for your friends list.
> - Select your privacy options. Next to “Friend List”, click the    drop-down menu to see your privacy options. If you don’t want anyone  to see your friends list, select “Only Me”. You can also set it to a  custom setting, or to one of the lists you’ve created.

[Source](http://www.wikihow.com/Hide-Friends-on-Facebook).